# PostgreSQL - Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: server, python, postgresql

I have a bot that runs on my Windows machine and I recently bought an Ubuntu virtual server. After a series of like infinite errors, I just reset the server completely and retrying from scratch. You can look here to see another post of some of my previous errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63310926/no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host-connect-call-failed-invalid-data-directory-for?noredirect=1#comment111984138_63310926

So now when I try to start my bot, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 950, in <module>
    bot.loop.run_until_complete(create_db_pool())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "bot.py", line 160, in create_db_pool
    bot.pg_con = await asyncpg.create_pool(database='xxx', user='postgres', password='???')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 398, in _async__init__
    await self._initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 426, in _initialize
    await first_ch.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 125, in connect
    self._con = await self._pool._get_new_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 468, in _get_new_connection
    con = await connection.connect(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1718, in connect
    return await connect_utils._connect(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 663, in _connect
    con = await _connect_addr(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 642, in _connect_addr
    await asyncio.wait_for(connected, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 483, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidAuthorizationSpecificationError: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

The database, user, and password are all correct though. It's working even right now as the bot is running on my Windows machine, which is why I think this is an Ubuntu specific issue. My listen addresses set to"

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

and my pg_hba.conf set to:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS             METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::/0                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
host    replication     all             ::/0                 md5
```

It used to have the default IP but I tried to make it open for any connections with the password, but the Ubuntu server still can't connect to it. Also, I don't seem to have this file naturally on my Ubuntu system at the moment. I can edit it from my Windows machine but I don't know if that affects both or not. I don't fully understand the database but I'm pretty sure it's hosted by my own PC? I can also bring the file itself manually to the Ubuntu server but I don't want to mess anything up again and be even more stuck. Changing `host` to `local` only seemed to make the database stop working on my Windows machine.

I've been stuck on this for a really long time and I have no idea what to do. I really hope someone knows the issue and I hope I've given enough information. Thank you.